# How to go about data modelling?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-modeling

I've spent the last 2 hours or so figuring out how to apply it to my two variables. I am supposed to demonstrate/explain how I would handle the relationship of the two following variables in data modelling:

```
   Pressure24h       DangerLevel24h     
     1000.2                45
     1014.8                90
     990.8                 14
     998.4                 95
     1002.1                46
     1006                  21
```

There is another 185,000 data to work with but that's just a very small sample of it. **Pressure24h** is measured in hectopascals and **DangerLevel24h** is measured in percentage. That's the only information I have to work with.
Is there any method that can be used to approach this?

I created a scatter plot to show the relationship but that was as far as I have gotten so far.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty5Yn.png

Comment: What's your data type? Is it a `pandas` or just a `2d numpy array`

Comment: Also, you could try generating a relationship with scatterplot to predict the future values. [Line of Best Fit (LOBF)](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/line-of-best-fit)

Comment: Data type for both variables is a float and I'm using pandas

Comment: Did you try predicting values using LOBF?

Comment: Yeah I did, I created a scatter plot trying to predict the values but it comes up with a massive blue blob (I added a photo to my main post). From what I can tell, it shows no relationship but I'm not sure if I did it correct or not.

Comment: I'll add my code for the predicting, check if that helps!

Comment: I'd start with calculation of average and std. deviation of `DangerLevel24h` for each distinct value of `Pressure24h`. Then I'd chart results and, apply some  regression analysis.

Comment: See, there are various methods. But the best one for your case would be `pearson's theory of correlation` which is somewhat similar to `LOBF`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code as discussed in the comments:

```
def lobf(*cords):
    cords = cords[0]
    print(cords)
    x_mean, y_mean = 0, 0
    print(cords)
    for x, y in cords:
        x_mean += x # get x sum
        y_mean += y # get y sum
    x_mean /= len(cords) # get x mean
    y_mean /= len(cords) # get y mean
    # Step 2 from https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/line-of-best-fit
    sigma_numerator, sigma_denominator = 0, 0
    for xi, yi in cords:
        sigma_numerator += (xi - x_mean)*(yi - y_mean) # get numerator
        sigma_denominator += (xi - x_mean)**2 # get denominator
    m = sigma_numerator/sigma_denominator # get slope
    c = y_mean - m*x_mean # get y-intercept
    return m ,c

data_values = [(2,2), (4,4)] # Sample data value you can put yours here
# Creating a for loop for every increment of 5 to avoid the blue blob you got.
# You can change the increment as per your choice
predicted_values = []
increment = 5
m ,c = lobf(data_values)
for i in range(data_values[-1][0]+increment, len(data_values)*100, increment): # You can consider dangerlevel24h as your x
    """
    Starts with incrementing the last x value of your data
    """
    predicted_values.append((i,i*m + c)) # appends x, y
print(predicted_values)
```

You can then plot every value from `predicted_values`. By iterating through every 5th or your desired iteration, you can avoid blue blobs to form. Also, this method will help you in predicting future values that aren't in your data. You can also try using Pearson's Theory of Correlation which is related to this method.
[image]